# how to show data in a list for android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, arraylist, android-activity

Can anyone help me create an activity for Android to show all data from a table (named `fac_info`) in a list, where each column in the list has two buttons, one of them for updating and another one for deleting the data?

This is my database adapter:

```
package com.ayaan;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DBAdapter {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";// row id
    public static final String KEY_FACNAME = "Fname";// Faculty name
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "Password";// password
    public static final String KEY_CODE = "Code";// subject code or name
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "Phone";// phone
    public static final String KEY_USN = "Usn";// usn or student name
    public static final String KEY_SNAME = "Sname";// name or student ID
    public static final String KEY_ATTEND = "Attended";// attending
    public static final String KEY_MISSED = "Missed";// missing
    public static final String KEY_CHECKBOX = "Check";// check box
    public static final String KEY_TOTAL = "Total";// finding total date
    public static final String KEY_ADMIN = "Admin";//
    public static final String KEY_PASS1 = "Pass1";
    public static final String KEY_PASS2 = "Pass2";
    private static final String TAG = "STUDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME1 = "Student1";// DB Name
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE1 = "fac_info";// faculty table
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "stu_info";// student info
                                                                // table
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE3 = "class_total";//
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE4 = "admin_values";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;// DB version

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table fac_info (_id integer primary key autoincrement, Fname text not null, Password text not null, Code text not null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE1 = "create table stu_info (_id integer primary key autoincrement, Sname text not null, Usn text not null, Code text not null, Attended integer, Missed integer, Phone text not null, Percent integer);";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE2 = "create table class_total (_id integer primary key autoincrement, Code text not null,Total integer);";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE3 = "create table admin_values (_id integer primary key autoincrement, Admin text not null, Pass1 text not null, Pass2 text not null);";



    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;//* this is instance of the class
    private final Context context;//*this is context of the class
    private SQLiteDatabase db;//*this is for SQLite

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {//*(DBAdapter) is the name of our java class
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME1, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            //*this above just initializing variable
            //*super(context, name of a DB, by default is(null), DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {//*we have to have this method, because of DatabaseHelper
            long x;
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE1);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE2);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {//*we have to have this method, because of DatabaseHelper
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PESITMSESTUDENT");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    // ---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        Log.i(TAG, "opening the database");
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    // ---closes the database---
    public void close() {
        Log.i(TAG, "closing the database");
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    // ---insert a title into the database---
    public long insertRecord(String fname, String pass, String code) {
        long x;

        Log.i(TAG, "INSERTING A FACULTY RECORD");
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_FACNAME, fname);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, pass);
        initialValues.put(KEY_CODE, code);
        x = db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, initialValues);

        return x;
    }

    public long insertStudentRecord(String sname, String usn, String code,
            int att, int miss, String phone) {
        long x;

        Log.i(TAG, "INSERTING A STUDENT RECORD");
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_SNAME, sname);
        initialValues.put(KEY_USN, usn);
        initialValues.put(KEY_CODE, code);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ATTEND, att);
        initialValues.put(KEY_MISSED, miss);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);

        x = db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, initialValues);

        return x;
    }

    public long insertClass(String Code, int Count) {
        long x;

        Log.i(TAG, "INSERTING A COUNT RECORD");
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_CODE, Code);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TOTAL, Count);
        x = db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE3, null, initialValues);
        return x;
    }

    // ---retrieves all the student records---
    public Cursor getAllRecords() {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_FACNAME,
                KEY_PASSWORD, KEY_CODE }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getAllRecordsBy() {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE2, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_SNAME,
                KEY_USN, KEY_CODE, KEY_ATTEND, KEY_MISSED, KEY_PHONE }, null,
                null, null, null, null);
    }

    // ---retrieves a particular student record---
    public Cursor getRecordByName(String code) throws SQLException {
        Log.i("Ayaan", "GETTING STUDENT RECORD");
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE1, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, KEY_FACNAME, KEY_PASSWORD, KEY_CODE }, KEY_CODE
                + "=" + "\"" + code + "\"", null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public Cursor getCount(String code) throws SQLException {
        Log.i("Ayaan", "GETTING STUDENT RECORD");
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE3, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, KEY_CODE, KEY_TOTAL }, KEY_CODE + "=" + "\"" + code
                + "\"", null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public Cursor getRecordByUsn(String Code, String usn) throws SQLException {
        Log.i("Ayaan", "getRecordByUsn()");
        Cursor mCursor;
        mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE2,
                new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_SNAME, KEY_USN, KEY_CODE,
                        KEY_ATTEND, KEY_MISSED, KEY_PHONE }, KEY_CODE + "=?"
                        + " AND " + KEY_USN + "=?", new String[] { Code, usn },
                null, null, null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            Log.i("Ayaan", "cursor not null");
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public Cursor getRecordBycode(String code) throws SQLException {
        Log.i("Ayaan", "GETTING STUDENT RECORD");
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE2, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, KEY_SNAME, KEY_USN, KEY_CODE, KEY_ATTEND,
                KEY_MISSED, KEY_PHONE }, KEY_CODE + "=" + "\"" + code + "\"",
                null, null, null, null, null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public Cursor getRecordTotal(String code) throws SQLException {
        Log.i("Ayaan", "GETTING STUDENT RECORD");
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE3, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, KEY_CODE, KEY_TOTAL }, KEY_CODE + "=" + "\"" + code
                + "\"", null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public void update(String Name,String phone,String code){

        db.execSQL("Update "+DATABASE_TABLE2+" set "+KEY_SNAME+"="+Name+","+KEY_PHONE+"="+phone+" where "+KEY_CODE+"="+code);

    }

    public boolean checkAvailability(String code,String Name){//unic

        Cursor c=db.query(DATABASE_TABLE2, new String[]{KEY_SNAME},KEY_CODE+"=?" , new String[]{code}, null, null, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SNAME)).equals(Name)){

            return false;
        }
        else 
            return true;

    }

    public int getTotalBySCODE(String SCODE){

        Cursor c=db.query(DATABASE_TABLE3, new String[]{KEY_TOTAL}, "Code=?", new String[]{SCODE}, null, null, null);
        c.moveToNext();

        int total=Integer.parseInt(c.getColumnName(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TOTAL)));

        return total;
    }

    public Cursor getRecordById(int id) throws SQLException {
        Log.i("Ayaan", "GETTING STUDENT RECORD by id");
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE2, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, KEY_SNAME, KEY_USN, KEY_CODE, KEY_ATTEND,
                KEY_MISSED, KEY_PHONE }, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public void updateattend(int id, int new_att) throws SQLException {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_ATTEND, new_att);
        db.update(DATABASE_TABLE2, values, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null);
    }

    public void updatemissed(int id, int new_miss) throws SQLException {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_MISSED, new_miss);
        db.update(DATABASE_TABLE2, values, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null);
    }

    public void updatecount(int id, int count) throws SQLException {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TOTAL, count);
        db.update(DATABASE_TABLE3, values, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null);
    }

    public void deleteStudentRecord(int id) {
        Log.i("ROOPA", "Trying To Delete Record");

        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE2, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: No. We cannot create it for you. We can however help **YOU** doing so, if at least you start trying.

Comment: but sir, thousand times I tried, I looked many tutorials, But I couldn't make it! this database a bit different than any other databases that I saw in tutorials.. that is why I said "any one can create for me?"

Comment: !. Watch "The World of ListView" (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DwDBM6wVEO70&ei=Dsl8U6XnCdXeoASd7ICQCA&usg=AFQjCNGAklAgezvQNN0PVmomzRjd7ci2uQ&sig2=_tTjaoumekxsw3-tbDz49g). 2. Learn how to use `Cursor` and `CursorAdapter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is build the object that will populate the list. This would contain the database column string, and the two buttons , one for updating and one for deleting. I would start with somenthing like this (in this example each object that populates the list is having an image and a text, your should take out the image and put two buttons instead:

```
public class TitleNavigationAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ImageView imgIcon;
private TextView txtTitle;
private ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem> spinnerNavItem;
private Context context;

public TitleNavigationAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem> spinnerNavItem) {
    this.spinnerNavItem = spinnerNavItem;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return spinnerNavItem.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int index) {
    return spinnerNavItem.get(index);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_queues, null);
    }

    imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
    txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

    imgIcon.setImageResource(spinnerNavItem.get(position).getIcon());
    imgIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txtTitle.setText(spinnerNavItem.get(position).getTitle());
    return convertView;
}


@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_queues, null);
    }

    imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
    txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

    imgIcon.setImageResource(spinnerNavItem.get(position).getIcon());        
    txtTitle.setText(spinnerNavItem.get(position).getTitle());
    return convertView;
}
```

}

public class SpinnerNavItem {

```
private String title;
private int icon;

public SpinnerNavItem(String title, int icon){
    this.title = title;
    this.icon = icon;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return this.title;      
}

public int getIcon(){
    return this.icon;
}
```

}

So then your list type will be SpinnerNavItem in this case. Try starting with this maybe and i will help you out,
Regards

Comment: Ok, this is the first step, as u show, u already have the Data adapter, the next step is thinking how to make list with several columns, maybe put more than one list together, or maybe using a gridm but withi this code u will be able to generate Object for any kind of structure